# Vue.js on iOS Safari 5.1

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, legacy

I wrote a tiny documentation app in Vue.js, which I would love to run on my old first gen iPad. The iPad is running iOS Safari (Version 5.1.1), which is however missing some key ECMA5 features. By default, I wasn't able to run Vue on it, so I was hoping I could just use some polyfills. I fiddled around with Babel (later polyfill.io) but kept getting a vague `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function` error on the iPad which I couldn't debug further as the iOS 5 console is very rudimentary. So I was hoping someone else had an idea of how I could make it work.

I would like to use the old iPad because the documentation task is very simple (so is the app, simple offline sync capabilites with PouchDB/Vue stack and very basic UI), the iPad is in good conditions, and I think it would be more sustainable to put it in good use rather than throwing it away :)

Thanks for your help!

P.S. [here's a fiddle of the app](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/4805/)

Comment: It would probably be better if you pasted the babel generated code. There are many things you use that arent supported in older browsers (like arrow functions). The way your code is right now, it is quite hard for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @acdcjunior! I updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/5448/) with the Babel generated code where I used `"browsers": "ios_saf 5.1"` as a target in the preset env. However, I eventually got the code to run on the iPad by additionally using the [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) library. The next issue I ran into was related to PouchDB not being able to sync with the old WebSQL version used in Safari. But switching to the last supported Chrome version on iOS 5.1.1 solved the issue. Just leaving this here for anyone who may also try this.

Comment: Just confirming that I am using Vue, having to target iOS 5.1, and still feeling your pain in 2020..